# HTML inserts space between the first occurrence of quotes

Tags: html

This drives me crazy. I want to pass a string literal as a parameter to a function in HTML **onclick** property containing a double quote.

My HTML element looks like this:

```
<button onclick = "ok_button_click(""Harry Potter "")" type="button" class="btn btn-default">ok</button>
```

But when I load the page and open it by Inspect Element, I see a space inserted between the first quote resulting in this:

```
<button onclick = "ok_button_click(" "Harry Potter"")" type="button" class="btn btn-default">bad</button>
```

Why does the browser insert a space ???

Comment: in HTML you escape a quote with an HTML entity `&quot;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass a string value with quotes then you have to use `&quot;` like this:

```
<button onclick = "ok_button_click('&quot;Harry Potter&quot;')" type="button" class="btn btn-default">bad</button>
```

If you just want to pass in a string literal you can just use a single quote (or the opposite of what the attribute started with) like this:

```
<button onclick = "ok_button_click('Harry Potter')" type="button" class="btn btn-default">bad</button>
```

Comment: Thank you much. Exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when the DOM is being parsed the browser uses `"` as delimiters, so in your case it is assigning `ok_button_click(` to the attribute `onclick` and `Harry Potter` as a separate (and unknown) attribute.

A better way of writing this code would be mixing single and double quotes as in:

```
<button onclick="ok_button_click('Harry Potter')" type="button" class="btn btn-default">ok</button>
```

A good start on HTML debugging is to run it through a validator, like in https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<button onclick = 'ok_button_click("Harry Potter")' type="button" class="btn btn-default">ok</button>
```